# Erro de Sintax no python com sql

Tags: python, sql

Alguem poderia me ajudar com esse erro ?

Este codigo abaixo.

```
def confirmar_convidados():
    conexao = sqlite3.connect('convidados.db')
    c = conexao.cursor()

    valores_dia = c.execute(f"SELECT Dia1, Dia2, Dia3, Dia4, Dia5 FROM convidados WHERE RG = {entry_Dia1}").fetchall()
    dias = [d + 1 for d in valores_dia[0]]  # valores_dia é uma lista com uma tupla
    c.execute(
        f"UPDATE convidados SET Dia1 = {dias[0]}, Dia2 = {dias[1]}, Dia3 = {dias[2]}, Dia4 = {dias[3]}, Dia5{dias[5]} WHERE RG = {entry_Dia1}"
    )
    # Commit as mudanças:
    conexao.commit()

    # Fechar o banco de dados:
    conexao.close()
```

Esta me apresentando esse erro:

```
valores_dia = c.execute(f"SELECT Dia1, Dia2, Dia3, Dia4, Dia5 FROM convidados WHERE RG = {entry_Dia1}").fetchall()
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Talvez seja o datatype do seu campo RG. Caso ele esteja como string e você esteja passando um valor fora de aspas (por exemplo um RG no formato xx.xxx.xxx-x) então dará erro de syntax ao encontrar o ponto.

```
def confirmar_convidados():
    conexao = sqlite3.connect('convidados.db')
    c = conexao.cursor()

    valores_dia = c.execute(f"SELECT Dia1, Dia2, Dia3, Dia4, Dia5 FROM convidados WHERE RG = '{entry_Dia1}'").fetchall()
    dias = [d + 1 for d in valores_dia[0]]  # valores_dia é uma lista com uma tupla
    c.execute(
        f"UPDATE convidados SET Dia1 = {dias[0]}, Dia2 = {dias[1]}, Dia3 = {dias[2]}, Dia4 = {dias[3]}, Dia5{dias[5]} WHERE RG = '{entry_Dia1}'"
    )
    # Commit as mudanças:
    conexao.commit()

    # Fechar o banco de dados:
    conexao.close()
```